# How to add missing jars in Eclipse Maven based project

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I am new to maven with eclipse. I am using m2e plugin(version 1.2.0).

i have imported maven project, it is showing build path errors due to some jars are missing.
How to add those jars to the build path. Do i need to download manually and add to the eclipse build.

i am learning about pom.xml, please help me.

[image: Build errors in maven project]

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7672933

Comment: Try to build your project on command line via **mvn clean package**.

Comment: its because of legacy URL http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/ i have updated it. And everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should add dependency of missing jar into pom.xml file.
As soon as you add them , eclipse will automatically download those jar files for you.
You can easily find  maven dependencies on google.