# Load Naïve Bayes model in java code using weka jar

Tags: java, weka, naivebayes

I have used **weka** and made a Naive Bayes classifier, by using weka GUI. Then I have saved this model by following this [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/save-machine-learning-model-make-predictions-weka/). Now I want to load this model through Java code but I am unable to find any way to load a saved model using weka.

This is my requirement that I have to made model separately and then use it in a separate program.

If anyone can guide me in this regard I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily load a saved model in java using this command:

```
Classifier myCls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(pathToModel);
```

For a complete workflow in Java I wrote the following article in SO Documentation, now copied here:

## Text Classification in Weka

#### Text Classification with LibLinear

- Create training instances from .arff file

  ```
  private static Instances getDataFromFile(String path) throws Exception{

      DataSource source = new DataSource(path);
      Instances data = source.getDataSet();

      if (data.classIndex() == -1){
          data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
          //last attribute as class index
      }

      return data;    
  }
  ```

---

```
Instances trainingData = getDataFromFile(pathToArffFile);
```

- Use **StringToWordVector** to transform your string attributes to number representation:

  - Important features of this filter:

    1. tf-idf representation
    2. stemming
    3. lowercase words
    4. stopwords
    5. n-gram representation*

  ```
  StringToWordVector() filter = new StringToWordVector();    
  filter.setWordsToKeep(1000000);
  if(useIdf){
      filter.setIDFTransform(true);
  }
  filter.setTFTransform(true);
  filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
  filter.setOutputWordCounts(true);
  filter.setMinTermFreq(minTermFreq);
  filter.setNormalizeDocLength(new SelectedTag(StringToWordVector.FILTER_NORMALIZE_ALL,StringToWordVector.TAGS_FILTER));
  NGramTokenizer t = new NGramTokenizer();
  t.setNGramMaxSize(maxGrams);
  t.setNGramMinSize(minGrams);    
  filter.setTokenizer(t);     
  WordsFromFile stopwords = new WordsFromFile();
  stopwords.setStopwords(new File("data/stopwords/stopwords.txt"));
  filter.setStopwordsHandler(stopwords);
  if (useStemmer){
      Stemmer s = new /*Iterated*/LovinsStemmer();
      filter.setStemmer(s);
  }
  filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);
  ```

  - Apply the filter to trainingData: `trainingData = Filter.useFilter(trainingData, filter);`
  - Create the LibLinear Classifier

    1. SVMType 0 below corresponds to the L2-regularized logistic regression
    2. Set `setProbabilityEstimates(true)` to print the output probabilities

       `Classifier cls = null;
       LibLINEAR liblinear = new LibLINEAR();
       liblinear.setSVMType(new SelectedTag(0, LibLINEAR.TAGS_SVMTYPE));
       liblinear.setProbabilityEstimates(true);
       // liblinear.setBias(1); // default value
       cls = liblinear;
       cls.buildClassifier(trainingData);`
  - Save model

    `System.out.println("Saving the model...");
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+"mymodel.model"));
    oos.writeObject(cls);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();`
  - Create testing instances from `.arff` file

    Instances trainingData = getDataFromFile(pathToArffFile);
  - Load classifier

  `Classifier myCls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(path+"mymodel.model");`

  - **Use the same StringToWordVector filter as above or create a new one for testingData, but remember to use the trainingData for this command:`filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);`** *This will make training and testing instances compatible.
    Alternatively you could use `InputMappedClassifier`*
  - Apply the filter to testingData: `testingData = Filter.useFilter(testingData, filter);`
  - Classify!

  1.Get the class value for every instance in the testing set

  for (int j = 0; j < testingData.numInstances(); j++) {
      double res = myCls.classifyInstance(testingData.get(j));
   }
  *`res` is a double value that corresponds to the nominal class that is defined in `.arff` file. To get the nominal class use : `testintData.classAttribute().value((int)res)`*

---

2.Get the probability distribution for every instance

```
 for (int j = 0; j < testingData.numInstances(); j++) {
    double[] dist = first.distributionForInstance(testInstances.get(j));
 }
```

*`dist` is a double array that contains the probabilities for every class defined in `.arff` file*

*Note. Classifier should support probability distributions and enable them with: `myClassifier.setProbabilityEstimates(true);`*

Comment: This code is working fine when I am using it in a simple java project. When I shifted to Java EE and used this code to get the model object, it gave me exception as,
cannot assign instance of java.util.ArrayList to field weka.core.Instances.m_Attributes of type weka.core.FastVector in instance of weka.core.Instances

   It is strange same code is working in simple Java project but problem in Java EE.

Comment: It is strange indeed. Are you using the same version of Weka? Cause to my best of knowledge FastVector class is deprecated. Maybe this is causing the issue.

Comment: Previously I was using weka.jar but it does not have Maven for it but Maven exist for weka-stable 3.6.6 . I am using that and got this exception. To avoid from library confusion I also used previous lib Weka.jar through class path. On that I got ClassNotFound exception. So in JavaEE no matter use which lib got exceptions.

Comment: I think that 3.6.6 weka version causing the exception. ClassNotFound exception is caused because the jar is not linked properly. Try following insructions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672933/maven-how-to-include-jars-in-eclipse-which-are-not-available-in-repository to link your jar. By the way what version is the weka.jar ?

Comment: Once I downloaded it from Weka site. No version is mentioned with its name.

Comment: I found weka.jar is 3.7.12

Comment: I found maven for weka dev 3.7.12 . That did not helped too. Then I go with latest version of weka-dev maven (3.9.1) and now issue is resolved. Thank a lot for staying with me in this issue. Your talk about version no really helped a lot.

Comment: glad i could help :)