# Weka StringToWordVector attributes omitted

Tags: weka

I´m working with Weka. My problem is, that some of the attributes are omitted after using StringToWordVector. So here is my code:

This is the ARFF file before using any filter:

```
@relation QueryResult

@attribute class {Qualität,Bord,Kite,Harness}
@attribute text {evo,foil,end,fin,edg}

@data
Qualität,evo
Bord,foil
Kite,end
Harness,fin
Qualität,edg
```

Here is my java code:

```
 Instances train = new Instances(loadInstancesForWeka("root","",sqlCommand));
 train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 2);
 System.out.println(train);

 NominalToString filter1 = new NominalToString();
 filter1.setInputFormat(train);
 train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter1);
 System.out.println("\nSelect nach NominaltoString \n"+train); 

 //filter
 StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
 filter.setInputFormat(train);
 train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);
```

After using the Vector it looks like this:

```
@relation 'QueryResult-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-Clast-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R2-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-stopwords-handlerweka.core.stopwords.Null-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute class {Qualität,Bord,Kite,Harness}
@attribute edg numeric
@attribute evo numeric
@attribute foil numeric
@attribute end numeric
@attribute fin numeric

@data
{2 1}
{0 Bord,3 1}
{0 Kite,4 1}
{0 Harness,5 1}
{1 1}
```

So why are the attributes "foil,end,fin" omitted? Thank you for your help.

Comment: My code is based on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935193/simple-text-classification-using-naive-bayes-weka-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any attributes omitted from your output. The output is in [sparse ARFF format](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/arff_stable/#sparse-arff-files):

> Sparse ARFF files are very similar to ARFF files, but data with value
>   0 are not explicitly represented. ...
>
> Each instance is surrounded by
>   curly braces, and the format for each entry is:
>   `[index] [space] [value]` where `index` is the attribute index (starting from 0).

So for the third instance in your example,

```
{0 Kite,4 1}
```

means that attribute 0 for this instance is `Kite`, attribute 4 (i.e. 'end') is `1`, and the other attributes are `0`.

It makes sense for `StringToWordVector` to produce sparse output because it creates a lot of new attributes, most of which will be 0 for each instance. If you need the non-sparse version you can use `weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.SparseToNonSparse`.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot. I have another question. I want the data to be classified in categories (as above "Qualität,..."): but I also want to have the prediction whether they are positive/ negative/ neutral. Do I have to do the classfication again or is there a special method for this?